# Image Upload issue with retrofit for android 10 kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, multipartform-data, scoped-storage

Api Interface :

```
@Multipart
@POST(AppConstants.UPDATE_PRODUCT)
fun updateProduct(
    @Header("Authorization") auth: String,
    @Part("product_id") id: RequestBody,
    @Part("title") title: RequestBody,
    @Part("description") description: RequestBody,
    @Part("price") price: RequestBody,
    @Part image: MultipartBody.Part
) : Call<UpdateProductResponse>?
```

Intent :

```
val photoIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).apply {
                    type = "image/*"
                    addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                }
                startActivityForResult(photoIntent, UPLOAD_IMAGE)
```

Activity result :

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == UPLOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.contentResolver, data.data)
            update_iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap)

            val imageType = contentResolver.getType(data.data!!)
            val extension = imageType!!.substring(imageType.indexOf("/") + 1)

            val file = File(getPath(data.data!!, this)!!)
            
            //val byte = contentResolver.openInputStream(data.data!!)
            //val contentPart = InputStreamRequestBody("image/*".toMediaType() , contentResolver , data.data!!)

            //filePartImage = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image" , file.name , contentPart)
            data.data!!.let {
                application.contentResolver.openInputStream(it)?.use { inputStream ->
                    filePartImage = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                        "image",
                        "" + file.name, //or "image.$extension" none of the two works
                        inputStream.readBytes().toRequestBody("image/*".toMediaType())
                    )
                }
            }
            showMessage(this, "" + getString(R.string.image_uploaded))
        } else {
            showMessage(this, "" + "File upload failed!")
        }
    }
}
```

Api call :
Here filePartImage is global variable like this : private var filePartImage: MultipartBody.Part? = null

```
    RetrofitClientInstance().createService(ArtOFiestaServiceClass::class.java).updateProduct(
        "Bearer " + Prefs.getString("token", ""),
        id.trim().toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaType()),
        update_name.text.toString().trim().toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaType()),
        update_desc.text.toString().trim().toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaType()),
        update_price.text.toString().trim().toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaType()),
        filePartImage!!
    )?.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<UpdateProductResponse> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<UpdateProductResponse>,
            response: Response<UpdateProductResponse>
        )
```

Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

I have developed it's backend in node js and using multer to upload files. I can upload a file using postman but fail from my mobile application. What is wrong with my code ? Could it be android Scoped Storage issue ?

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion`? if 30 `requestLegacyExternalStorage` won't work.

Comment: @ronnieotieno i dont get any error. I could also log my filePartImage var. I get undefined as file object in the backend. I have verified my backend and it's working perfectly fine.

Comment: @sdex my 'targetSdkVersion' is 30.

Comment: @sdex i removed `requestLegacyExternalStorage` and it still did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to `Scoped Storage`, because I am also facing the same problem as well.

My solution is convert `inputStream` to identical `File` and store it somewhere else. Then after upload, you may delete the file.

The idea is as below.

```
contentResolver.openInputStream(it)?.use { inputStream ->
    // STEP 1: Create a tempFile for storing the image from scoped storage. 
    val tempFile = createTempFile(this, fileName, extension)

    // STEP 2: copy inputStream into the tempFile
    copyStreamToFile(it, tempFile)

    // STEP 3: get file path from tempFile for further upload process. 
    val filePath = tempFile.absolutePath

    val requestFile: RequestBody = File(filePath).asRequestBody(fileType?.toMediaTypeOrNull())
    val body: MultipartBody.Part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", fileName, requestFile)
}
```

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun createTempFile(context: Context, fileName: String?, extension: String?): File {
    val storageDir: File? = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
    return File(storageDir, "$fileName.$extension")
}

fun copyStreamToFile(inputStream: InputStream, outputFile: File) {
    inputStream.use { input ->
        val outputStream = FileOutputStream(outputFile)
        outputStream.use { output ->
            val buffer = ByteArray(4 * 1024) // buffer size
            while (true) {
                val byteCount = input.read(buffer)
                if (byteCount < 0) break
                output.write(buffer, 0, byteCount)
            }
            output.flush()
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: You can actually debug for the ```Uri``` that you get. It is encoded and after my research, there is NO WAY to return a exact file path for it. No choice but to copy the ```inputStream``` to another file first everything you need to upload something.

Comment: what is meant by didnt work? can you show what is the error? or u can try debug it and see where is the error?

Comment: LOG - filePartImage object while calling api -> `E/TAG: updateItemApiCall: okhttp3.MultipartBody$Part@c6d66ae`

Comment: can you double confirm that your file path is working? and also, u can use debug mode to check what is the exact error on line ```MultipartBody```

Comment: filepath = `E/TAG: onActivityResult: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.artofiesta/files/Documents/image.jpeg`

Comment: can try and check this ```asRequestBody(fileType?.toMediaTypeOrNull())```? not sure will it affected or not

Comment: I can't believe. It worked ! Thank you soo much :)

Comment: Glad to hear it helps :)

Comment: Actually after having seen how it works, I have come up with an even better solution. You would definitely like to have a look at it. Would save a lot of unnecessary code.

Comment: Yea I can refer to your code to modified mine :)

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `.toRequestBody("image/*".toMediaType())` to `.toRequestBody(imageType.toMediaTypeOrNull)` did the job

```
if (requestCode == UPLOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.contentResolver, data.data)
            update_iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap)

            val imageType = contentResolver.getType(data.data!!)
            val extension = imageType!!.substring(imageType.indexOf("/") + 1)

            val file = File(getPath(data.data!!, this)!!)

            data.data!!.let {
                application.contentResolver.openInputStream(it).use { inputStream ->
                    filePartImage = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                        "image",
                        file.name,
                        inputStream!!.readBytes().toRequestBody(imageType.toMediaTypeOrNull())
                    )
                }
            }
```

Comment: but it is able to get app's level directory only right? if I want to get something from shared directory such as /Downloads, /Picture etc, the file path will return as ```content://document%038``` something like this.

Comment: yes. You may add a random string in place of file.name if it doesn't really matter. But this method does read your selected file properly.